# XPaths: Selecting specific elements

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I want to select p tags under a specific h2 tag from a div that has multiple h2 and p tags.
Here is the sample code for it:

```html
    <div class="main">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
```

and so on...

What would be the XPath for selecting the p tags after the first h2 tag but before the second h2 tags???

Comment: Perhaps try `//div[@class='main']/h2[2]/preceding-sibling::p`

Answer (score 0):

here's your `xpath`, you can use `axes` to get in between `h2` nodes.

```
div[@class='main']/p[preceding-sibling::h2[1] and following-sibling::h2[2]]
```

**input:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this
add the index of the tag `h2[index]`

example:
    //div[@class='main']/h2[1]/p